# Excel for Web Data Validation List Not Working with FILTER() function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, web, data-validation

I am using a combination of a data validation list - which contains zip codes - and the =FILTER() function to try and create a drop down list of zip codes for the user to search from.

When I remove the data validation list and only enter a zip code into cell B7 the =FILTER() formula in the screenshot works and displays the accounts associated with the entered zip code.

However, when I add a Data Validation list to cell B7 the formula stops working and reports "No Match Found".

One the desktop version of excel the Data Validation + FILTER function works but this is not the case using Excel for the Web.

Is it possible for a Data Validation List to work with the FILTER function is Excel for the Web? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

[Excel for Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaoHa.png)

Comment: Do you mean the data validation and the formula are both for cell B7? Or do you mean that you apply the data validation list to cell B4, then enter filter formula in cell B7?

Comment: I may be wording this incorrectly but in short I have a Data Validation list/dropdown in cell B4. I am trying to link a Filter formula to cell B4. With the desired outcome being the filter formula's output updating based on the value the user chooses from the Data Validation/dropdown list. Everything works as is on Excel for Desktop but when using Excel for the Web...failure. I am trying to understand why. And asking to see if there is alternative approach I can use to get similar results?

Comment: @Emily please see above

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I can not reproduce your issue. Here is my [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkHSR.gif).

Comment: I've had issues, in web and desktop Excel, where array formulae doesn't work well in the data validation list box. How are you defining your list? I found the best way is to name the range for the dropdown in the sheet say "list", and then in Data Validation enter `=list` only. This is especially true if list is defined say as `=UNIQUE(Sheet1!$A:$A)`.

Comment: @Emily Your example is perfect. That is exactly what I am trying to do. But for some reason my data validation list does not work with or update the Filter formula as yours does. Could it be that I am using named Tables in my formula? Or the formatting of the data used in the data validation list? Clearly your example shows that this can work in Excel for the Web.

Comment: @Mobus I will try this today. It has to be something with the format of the data or how the list is defined. I agree as Emily showed this can work in here sample.

Comment: Hi @Emily, can you please post the formula / range you used to define your Data Validation list?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I defined 2 Names, “Test11” and “Test22”, but I still can not reproduce your issue. [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faqOQ.jpg), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYdRf.jpg)